# using jquery function when added runat server tag with textbox inside grid view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have two textboxes for value conversion inside the gridview. Outside the gridview the jJquery function is working perfectly. But when I add the textboxes inside the gridview, it is not working.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridCustomer" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Reading">
            <ItemTemplate>                                               
               <input type="text" runat="server" id="nepaliDate9" value="2069-08-01"/>
               <input type="text" runat="server" id="englishDate9" value="2012-11-16"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
                placeholder: "select tole"
            });

            $("[id$=englishDate9]").change(function () {
                $("[id$=nepaliDate9]").val(AD2BS($("[id$=englishDate9]").val()));
            });

            $("[id$=nepaliDate9]").change(function () {
                $("[id$=englishDate9]").val(BS2AD($("[id$=nepaliDate9]").val()));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I also tried using asp textbox with `ClientIDMode="Static"` but still no use. While inspecting the textboxes, its showing::

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridCustomer$ctl02$nepaliDate9" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridCustomer_nepaliDate9_0" value="2069-08-01">

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridCustomer$ctl02$englishDate9" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridCustomer_englishDate9_0" value="2012-11-16">
```

I tried changing the function as ::

```
$('#<%=GridCustomer.ClientID%>').find("[id$=englishDate9]").change(function () {
    $('#<%=GridCustomer.ClientID%>').find("[id$=nepaliDate9]").val(AD2BS($("[id$=englishDate9]").val()));
});

$('#<%=GridCustomer.ClientID%>').find("[id$=nepaliDate9]").change(function () {
    $('#<%=GridCustomer.ClientID%>').find("[id$=englishDate9]").val(BS2AD($("[id$=nepaliDate9]").val()));
});
```

but still not working. Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things that you should take into consideration while using jQuery and `ASP.NET GridView`. I would want to point out some things that might help you to resolve the issue:

- First and Foremost, you must make sure that your ID attribute of the server control is not being modified as asp.net changes the ids so that every id is different based on the row, it probably includes row index at the end of the id with an underscore.

  In your case, it is `ContentPlaceHolder1_GridCustomer_nepaliDate9_0` which means, the text box *nepaliDate9* control is at zeroth row of the `GridCusomter` `GridView` which is inside a content place holder with the id `ContentPlaceHolder1`.

  So, in my opinion it is better to use classes to bind the events instead of IDs. In your case you should bind it like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridCustomer" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Reading">
            <ItemTemplate>                                               
               <input type="text" runat="server" id="nepaliDate9" class="nepaliDate9" value="2069-08-01"/>
               <input type="text" runat="server" id="englishDate9" class="englishDate9" value="2012-11-16"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".englishDate9").change(function () {
                $(".nepaliDate9").val(AD2BS($(this).val())); // I suppose you want to use the value of the currently changed item
            });

            $(".nepaliDate9").change(function () {
                $(".englishDate9").val(BS2AD($(this).val()));
            });
        });
</script>
```

- Secondly, you must check if your jquery events are being bound to the control or not. For some reasons, jQuery events are not bound to the controls e.g when scripts are loaded before the controls are rendered.

  You might want to try something like this to bind the controls:

```
$("body").on('change', "[id$=englishDate9]", function () {
    $("[id$=nepaliDate9]").val(AD2BS($("[id$=englishDate9]").val()));
});
```

- Thirdly, It is always a good idea to keep a track of the browser dev console so whenever there is some issue you immediately get the idea what went wrong.

Comment: the value of second text box of every row is changing whenever I make any changes in the first text box of any row. This solution is working perfect for only single row grid but whenever I have multiple rows, its not working... Please help!!!

Comment: @nischalinn, It was an idea to resolve it. If it works for one row, you must try to resolve it for your needs for every row. Nobody will post a complete module for you. These were the hints that woul have helped you to resolve it.